# no route matches even after adding route to routes.rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

This is the code in the view.

```
<% form_tag({:controller => 'users',
                  :action => 'test'}) do %>
        <%= text_field_tag(:search_options, params[:search_options])%>
        <%= submit_tag("Display text!")%>
      <% end -%>
```

I have a file test.html.erb and have also added get "users/test" to routes.rb still i'm getting Error: No route matches "/users/test"

Comment: The `rake routes` command is helpful for debugging these problems. I'd suggest adding the output of `rake routes | grep user` to your question, with a list of the actions defined in the `users_controller`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `form_tag` method creates a form to be send using HTTP POST by default. You state that the route you define in your `routes.rb` is a GET. So you have two options to fix this problem:

1. Change your route to `POST "users/test"`
2. Change your `form_tag` call to: `form_tag({:controller => 'users',                  :action => 'test'}, :method => :get)`